# Как указать связи между указателями и исходными данными?

Tags: c, visual-c++, boost, c++, сериализация

При сериализации в boost::serialization можно записать вектор `std::vector<int> base;`

И затем восстановить его. 
Можно записать указатель на этот вектор и так же восстановить. Можно записать `std::vector<int*> base` вектор с указателями и так же восстановить по значению.

Но как сделать(если можно), чтобы при сериализации сохранялись связи между исходными данными и указателями на них.

То есть чтобы при восстановлении

```
std::vector<int> <<------------------------------------------\
                                                             |
в контейнере `std::vector<int*>` хранились указатели на ---> |
```

Это можно сделать и вручную, но интересуют именно возможности boost.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp> 
#include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
std::system("chcp 1251");

// Исходные данные
std::vector<int> base;
base.push_back(77);

// вот здесь хранятся указатели на base
std::vector<int*> links;
links.push_back(&base[0]);

/// Здесь запись и востановление base
//
{
std::ofstream OA("file.txt");
std::cout << "\nдо base[0]=" << base[0];
boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(OA);
oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(base);
}
// очистка
base.clear();

{
std::ifstream IA("file.txt");
boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(IA);
ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(base);
std::cout << "\nпосле base[0]=" << base[0];
}

#ifdef здесь_ошибка_компиляции 
// error C2228: выражение слева от ".serialize" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение

/// Здесь запись и востановление links
//
{
std::ofstream OA("file.txt");
std::cout << "\nдо base[0]=" << links[0];
boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(OA);
oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(links);
}
// очистка
links.clear();

{
std::ifstream IA("file.txt");
boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(IA);
ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(links);
std::cout << "\nпосле base[0]=" << links[0];
}
#endif
```

Comment: Не думаю, что так 

    // Исходные данные
    std::vector<int> base;
    base.push_back(77);
    
    // вот здесь хранятся указатели на base
    std::vector<int*> links;
    links.push_back(&base[0]);


вообще правильно делать. 

Дело в том, что в конце-концов при очередном `base.push_back()` память, занимаемая элементами вектора `base` "переедет" на новое место, а вот кто для Вас скорректирует содержимое `links`?

Comment: Помню так: vector не гарантирует, list гарантирует, map не гарантирует?

Но на самом деле меня интересует массив:

    CELL ** cell;
    CELL * cell = &cell[0][0];

В некоторых местах для доступа к нему хранятся индексы. C ними проблем быть не должно.
int row;
int column;

А в других указатель на CELL*.
------------------------------

Comment: По тому, что узнал из документации, наверное так вообще не выйдет.
Указатели заново связываются только если вначале записать исходный объект, а затем следом указатель.

В boost xml тэгах архива(файла) есть такие параметры:

    class_id_reference
    object_id_reference

Тэг который содержит их? формирует объект который является указателем на указанные id_reference.

Но какой либо информации как их использовать не могу найти.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, крайне нежелательно работать с указателями на объекты в `std::vector`, потому что он не гарантирует, что данные не будут перемещены в памяти во время работы программы. Ваши указатели окажутся сломанными, и программа упадет или натворит бед. Вместо этого используйте `std::list`, он гарантированно не сломает ваши указатели.

Во-вторых, сначала загрузить массив, а потом создать массив с ссылками на него — нетипичная ситуация, и скорее всего она в Boost не реализована. Лучше и безопаснее будет реализовать это вручную.

И прежде чем доверять Бусту работать с указателями, подумайте, кто будет чистить память. Если вы загружаете из файла данные в виде указателей, то их придется вычищать вручную.